# Memory growing with byte array copy

Tags: c#, console-application

I have problem with simple byte[] copy. In ConsoleApplication i load 75MB DAT file into byte[]. After that i would like to cut array with function bellow.

```
public static byte[] SubArray(this byte[] Data, int Index, int Length = 0)
{
    if (Length == 0) Length = Data.Length - Index;
    byte[] Result = new byte[Length];
    Array.Copy(Data, Index, Result, 0, Length);
    return Result;
}
```

If i use only one **Data = Data.SubArray(32)**, memory grow from 100 to 180MB, but if i do a test with three times *Data = Data.SubArray(32)*, memory grow triple to 340MB. I suppose that old array is still in memory. How do i release old array from memory? I don't need it anymore and with more array sub in code memory growth to 2GB.

Comment: If you don't have other references to the "original" "big `Data`", then the GC will automatically collect it when you are low of memory. If you really really want to force a collection, `GC.Collect()` (normally you shouldn't do it). Note that if you execute the program under Visual Studio, the GC will collect less memory (it will be more conservative on what it can collect)

Comment: Can you paste your test code in too? Calling `GC.Collect()` is never a great idea. Instead I would refactor the testing code so that the originally byte[] Data is no longer in scope (i.e. falls outside of { }). This frees it up for collection by the GC. 

Alternatively you can set `Data = null` or `Data = new byte[0]`. This will change the variable pointer to a new array on the heap and the old array will no longer have references to it and be ready for collection.

Comment: GC.Collect() reduce memory about 2MB, don't work correctly for my problem. I have only one array and i need to cut him, i don't need copy in memory. I wish to have 180MB in memory and if i cut array repeatly, this memory have to reduce, not to growth.

Comment: I try Data = null, Data = new byte[0], nothing works. Visual Studio 2015 still show 348MB in memory.

Comment: You probably have chosen the wrong language for your task. You can't "free" memory. Also GC does not "free" memory (and as far as I understand it is not meant to), it only "collects" the garbage. As far as I know there are no handles to force CLR to actually free the memory, it will do it when it decides that it should be done.

Comment: *Visual Studio 2015 still show 348MB in memory.* I wrote explicitly *the GC will collect less memory (it will be more conservative on what it can collect)* **Memory occupation can be realiabily tested only outside Visual Studio.**

Comment: @xanatos and even outside of Visual Studio after full collection, finalizing and compacting CLR is not obliged to call `VirtualFree` for all logically free memory, is it?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Yes, but normally you should be able to see a big block of 50mb that "disappears" because it is freed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let the [Garbage Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) to do its thing. To make it easier for GC, you would normally set the old unused reference to null or replace it with a new reference value. GC needs some time to hit.